# Remove blobs of certain size from video mage OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following image coming from a segmentation network. [image]

This is the representation of a road(white), ground(blue) and threes(green) which can be seen clearly in the input image below.

[image]

As you can see the segmented image has a lot of unwanted blobs and rough edges. I would like to filter out these blobs and clean the edges.

I have tried a couple of different methods:
First I tried to detect the blobs and then fill in the blobs. This works really well but the problem is that my blobs are not shaped like a circle or a square. So when filling them in, not only the blob but also a area around it is filled in.

```
def filterBlobs(image,size):

    imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    # Detect blobs.
    keypoints = detector.detect(imageGray)

    for x in range(1,len(keypoints)):
        image=cv2.circle(image, (np.int(keypoints[x].pt[0]),np.int(keypoints[x].pt[1])), radius=np.int(keypoints[x].size), color=(0,255,0), thickness=-1)

return image
```

I have also tried to find all the contours with a certain size and fill those contours with a color. Only problem her is that if the contour is not closed it wont be filled. I tried to approximate the ploy of the contour with approxPolyDP and also tried convexHull but both did not gave nice results.

```
def filterContours(image,size):
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, 175, 200)

    cv2.imshow("canny", edged)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 100)


    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        print(area)
        #if area < size:
            #cv2.drawContours(image,[contour],0,255,-1)
        cv2.fillPoly(image, pts =[contour], color=(0,0,255), maxLevel=2)
        #cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        #hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

    return image
```

I have also tried medianblur. This gives a really nice smoothing of the edges but offcourse does not remove the blobs. I suspect the solution is a combination of medianblur and blob filling.

```
median = cv2.medianBlur(img, 21)
```

I also tried Morphological Transformations with open and close. While open gave the best result it was also not really good. This is because a lot of detail was lost with a large kernel size, there where still unwanted blobs and the edges where not smooth.

```
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

What I am ideally looking for is a method which cleans the segmented image in such a way that the segmented image clearly represents the road on the input image. And that all the noise from the segmented image is gone.

I think that it should look something like 4 blobs. 
1 in the middle for the road
1 blob on both sides of the road for the ground
1 blob in the back representing the threes

Please also provide a Python code example if possible. A c++ example is also welcome I can translate it to Python.

Thanks Sieuwe

EDIT: Forgot to add that this is running real time from a video feed. A FPS of around 15 to 20 is my target. Any heavy processing which takes a long time is not possible. It is running on a i7 and GTX1080 so there is enough power for moderate processing.

Comment: I do not understand why a blob would be different from a filled contour. You should threshold on each color and remove the contours from that. See cv2.inRange() for selecting a color range and thresholding to b/w. Some degree of smoothing can be done using morphology open or close

Comment: @fmw42 what I mean with filling a blob is that I want to change the color so smooth out the image. For example in the example above there is a white blob on the right side where actually the color Blue should be. I want to detect this white blob and recolor it in the color Blue.